# Memory leak or some other issues in my iPad application?

Tags: memory-leaks, memory-management, ipad

I am facing problems with my iPad application some times it gets hang-up my application and still I am not able to figure out the issues why it is happening again and again with my application. I have tested application through instrument. Please help me out how can I figure out what is the problem with my application or how to prevent memory related issues.

Comment: This question is _extremely_ ambiguous and very difficult to answer objectively. Please consider adding a lot more information, such as what you have used so far to try an track down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode) to help find memory leaks in Objective C programs, some integrated nicely on the OS X platform. Look for "instruments", "clang static analyzer", or "Leaks".