# valgrind and iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, memory-leaks, valgrind

I would like to use valgrind to detect leaks on iPhoneSimulator. I got the source for valgrind, compiled and installed. Added the following to my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

#ifdef VALGRIND_REXEC
    if (argc = 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-valgrind") != 0)) {
        execl(VALGRIND, VALGRIND, "--leak-check=full", "--dsymutil=yes", argv[0], "-valgrind", NULL);
    }
#endif
```

VALGRIND_REXEC is defined, when I try to Debug or Run my application I get the following error in the console

```
[Session started at 2011-03-14 16:21:27 +0000.]
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
open$UNIX2003 called from function main in image valgrind.
If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first.
```

Mac 10.6.5
Xcode 3.2.5
iOS 4.2

Do I need to compile valgrind in any special way, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Out of random curiosity, is there a reason the "Leaks" tool in Xcode won't do what you need it to?

- [Relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode).

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for your comment. When trying to use Leaks from Xcode I get the error "Target failed to run". When running target from Instruments I get "Failure while acquiring malloc pointers (LeakAgent32)". Cannot use Leaks, hence looking for alternate solutions.

Comment: Build & Analyze is also pretty good at finding potential leaks.

Comment: Valgrind does more than just memory leaks.  It's a comprehensive memory-usage analyzer, tracking things like writes outside of allocated memory, reads of uninitialized values, and so on.