# Iphone equivelant of DDMS Dump Heap (HPROF) into MAT (from Android)?

Tags: android, iphone, heap-memory, ddms

You can dump the heap from Android apps from DDMS using "Dump HPROF File", which opens into MAT. Its useful to track down sources of memory leaks etc. What is the equivalent on Iphone? A work mate is inquiring.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post, it lists many useful iPhone memory analysis tools.

[Memory leak detection tools in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode)

Comment: Cheers actually "Leaks" seems the common one but he already uses that. It just doesn't seem as thorough as DDBS + MAT to me