# Crash because of low Memory

Tags: iphone, ios4

My app crash on ipod 3g and in crash reporter file  the name of crash file is "low memory ..." does this crash because of low memory or this name is fake ?
What should i do to solve it ?

Comment: Why do you suspect that it's "fake"? What did your memory profiler say about your memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a fake name. First thing you should do is run the "leaks" performance tool on your app to see if you are leaking memory. This is most likely the problem, otherwise you are using too much memory and you need to find a way to do what you want with less memory.

Help with running the leaks program:
[Memory leak detection tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode)

Comment: How to find "run -> Start with Performance Tool -> Leaks" in Xcode 4

Comment: If you click and hold on the run button you will get a drop down. Select "Profile". Instruments will open and prompt you to choose a test. You will probably want to use "Leaks" and possibly "Allocations".

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a fake name, and to debug you should first use the `Instruments` app provided with xcode and specifically look at the 'Allocations' and 'Leaks' instruments from the library.

Run these on your app and it will help you to identify how and where your code is leaking so much memory that it causes the OS to kill it.

There's several ways you can reduce memory usage in a basic app, here's a couple of generic ones:

- Remember to release / autorelease **everything** you `alloc`
- Reuse table cells if applicable
- Try to cache things on disk, rather than in memory when loading from a resource
- Remove debug code / features