# Effective Xcode Debugging

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

When I got started in iOS dev, debugging in Xcode seemed like a pain. I used to get `exec_bad_access` issues & crashes at random points that took me ages to figure out the reasons behind.

I then stumbled upon Brad Larson's videos on debugging in Xcode and my life has never been the same. He showed how you could dynamically set a break point & get your app to break every time an exception was thrown. This allowed me to actually see the stack trace & figure out what was wrong in a jiffy. It made life a lot easier.

To the experienced developers out there, are there any more random tidbits such as this that you find useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO itself is a nice resource:

- [Hidden Features of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode)
- [How to print out the method name and line number and conditionally disable NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks)
- [Memory leak detection tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode)