# Mac OS dev - Tools for monitoring memory

Tags: xcode, cocoa, memory-management

Are there any tools that would allow me to monitor memory usage and leaks? For example, I want to track memory usage when releasing objects manually vs automatically with ARC enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory leak detection tools in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode)

Comment: @bryanmac not an exact duplicate (but close). this question asks about memory usage as well as leaks.

Comment: Also, that's an old question with some old answers. The Leaks, ObjectAlloc, and MallocDebug applications no longer exist, having been replaced with the Leaks and Allocations instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called instruments, you can acces it from Product -> Profile -> Leaks in xcode

Comment: Just looked at Instruments - seems quite mysterious to me. Thanks, I'll try to make sense of it!

Comment: This awesome tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial explains all you need

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is probably the easiest to use and does a pretty good job. It comes with Xcode and you can run it directly from Xcode when you launch your application.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is quite good at this, but still I find myself using the `leaks` and `heap` utilities quite often.