# how to solve memory iOS App Crashes?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, memory-management, crash

Last week I sent an app to iTunes Connect. All seemed to work fine, the app passed the Xcode validation after archiving, it did not (and it does not nowadays) crash on any point I tested.

For my surprise this app was rejected by apple yesterday leaving this message in resolution center: 
    We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

> We found that your app CRASHED ON LAUNCH on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> Your app may encounter this issue if it is using too much memory. To learn more about iOS memory usage and how to track memory usage and leaks, please see the Memory Usage Performance Guidelines.

Immediately, I tested the app on the simulator, because I do not own an iPhone 5, it launched correctly (IT DOES NOT CRASH). The only thing was that I found 3 memory leaks, I corrected them, but are they the problem of this crash?

So here are my questions:

- When they say "if IT is using too much memory", what are they making reference to? (The App or the device?)
- How can I test my app simulating the "over-use" of memory to? I want to do this just to see the crash log on Xcode, and to see if the leaks correction solved that.

Comment: Have you tested your application on **any** device? If not... you need to.

Comment: yes on an iPhone 4, 4s, iPad 3, iPad 1 and iPod 2
I only missed the iPhone 5 because I do not own one

Comment: already done, as I said I found 3 leaks and I solved them but I don't know if they were the main problem causing the crash. Thank you anyway

Comment: Also, Clean your build and reset all settings in your simulator and then test it again

Comment: But the problem is that I am not able to reproduce the crash, I can not make the app crash.

Comment: Pls run leaks instrument with your application.   Pls refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode

Comment: LEAKS ARE ALREADY FIXED. thanks for the answer...

Comment: If your application is crashing on launch for the testers but not for you, there's probably something about your configuration that doesn't match the test configuration. Try resetting one of your devices, installing NOTHING other than your application, and starting it up. And/or read the crash log Apple sent you.

Comment: @duskwuff I read the crash log Apple sent me. However, it says that 


Thread 0 crashed: 

>Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

>Thread 0 Crashed:


...


14  CDPI                           0x0005b19e 0x5a000 + 4510


This number makes reference to a function a button call when touching up inside. However, I tested the button and works fine. Furthermore it is not coherent when they tell it is a crash ON LAUNCH.

Comment: It's very likely a rotation problem.  They really effed things up there.  Try placing the simulator into different orientations before starting, and try deleting the app on the simulator before reinstalling/running, if you haven't done that much.

Comment: @HotLicks it was not the problem neither. I think that I will send the app again with the 3 leaks fixed, I hope they were the problem! I will post feedback! Thanks for your answer anyway!