# Customization of lazyTableImages sample code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to use code from [Apple's lazyTableImages sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) to realize async (non-blocking) loading of images (`UIImage`) from URL addresses.

I already have URL addresses for the images to be downloaded, so the `ParseOperation.h` and `ParseOperation.m` in the `lazyTableImages` sample project is not necessary.

However, I failed to apply the sample code into my project. I've got no idea on how to manually set images URLs, instead of parsing the XML to get URL addresses in the sample project.

Please shed some light on it. Thank you :D

Comment: goto my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352337/how-to-retrieve-images-from-server-asynchronously/16352794#16352794

Upvote if it is useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apple's lazyTableImages sample project the object of `AppRecord` is created inside `ParseOperation.m` and its been added to an array called `appRecordList`. Then that array is assigned to the array present in RootViewController `entries`. Instead here what you can do is, you can create the `AppRecord` object may be in viewDidLoad method of RootViewController  and set the image URL like `WilsonL` told to the appRecord object, then add it to the `entries` array.

This will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the URL string to  appRecord's imageURLStrin in the Project's RootViewController.m

i.e.

```
appRecord.imageURLString = YOUR URL STRING
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display image from url then use EGOImage.

[EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)

Comment: Thank you! I'll check your reference later :D