# UTableView scrolling slowly with images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have problem I am loading `UITableViewCell` with `images` all images shown to me but the problem is `UTableView` `scroll` very slow this is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customSearchesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell =[[customSearchesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];        
    }    

    searchobjectval =[self.arrSearchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.location.text =searchobjectval.location;
    cell.title.text = searchobjectval.title;
    cell.cost.text = searchobjectval.roomCost;
    cell.desc.text =searchobjectval.description;

    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    if (indexPath.row % 2)
    {
        UIColor* clr = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4f green:0.6f blue:0.8f alpha:1];
        myView.backgroundColor = clr;
    }
    else
    {
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    cell.backgroundView = myView;

    NSLog(@" search object image %@",searchobjectval.imgLink);

    UIImage *ret = [self imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.95.76.78/bedspace/new_arrivals_img/%@",searchobjectval.idVal ] cache:YES andsearchObj:searchobjectval];

    cell.imgVw.image = ret;

    return cell;
}

    // images caching in dictionary
    - (UIImage*)imageNamed:(NSString*)imageNamed cache:(BOOL)cache andsearchObj:(clsSearch *)searchObj
    {
         UIImage* retImage = [staticImageDictionary objectForKey:imageNamed];
        @try
        {
            if (retImage == nil)
            {
                retImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageNamed]]];
                if (cache)
                {
                    if (staticImageDictionary == nil)
                        staticImageDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

                    [staticImageDictionary setObject:retImage forKey:imageNamed];

                }               
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            NSLog(@"exception %@",exception);
        }
        @finally {
            NSLog(@"finally block execute here");
        }

        return retImage;
    }
```

Kindly tell me how I can fix this problem, I had paste the code inside `if (cell == nil)` but not successfull yet.

Comment: `retImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageNamed]]];` :-> do this asynchronously.

Comment: load images in background.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the synchronous loading of images into the tablecell.Make it asynchronous and it will work fine

Use this

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
 dispatch_async(queue, ^{
       NSString *strURL = url here;
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
       UIImage *image = nil;
       if(data)
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           //now use image in image View  or anywhere according to your requirement.
           if(image)
             yourImgView = image
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `SDWebImage` to load image from webserver.

Comment: Click...https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

`retImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageNamed]]];`

for every cell appears, this line starts fetching data (image) from the server. As well as you start scrolling the `UITable`, the request will go to the server to get the image, so you should grab images from the server using `NSThread`.

Try my code here, upvote if it is useful.
[How to retrieve images from server asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352337/how-to-retrieve-images-from-server-asynchronously/16352794#16352794)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the method: `[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageNamed]]];` runs on the `main thread`.

Refer NSOperatioQueue Samople Code or ASIHTTP library for downloading images asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage library which not only loads the images asynchronusly but also makes your tableView scrolling very good and fast.

you can get the library from here.. https://github.com/nicholjs/SDWebImage-with-loading-progress